# solution for duplicate column values and its corresponding un-duplicated column

Tags: python, awk

Say for eg my input file - file1.tsv has the following 2 columns

```
type         grocery
fruits       orange
fruits       apple
fruits       kiwi
greens       collard
greens       spinach
```

The desired result is

```
type         grocery
fruits       orange, apple, kiwi
greens       collard, spinach
```

I could read duplicates in column 1 as dictionary but I unable to append un-duplicated column 2 value with comma. Is there a quick solution to this in python ?

Answer (score 2):

If the file is grouped by column 1:

```
awk 'p==$1{s=s ", " $2; next} {if(p)print s; p=$1; s=$0} END{print s}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply store the values as an array:

```
types = ['type','fruits','greens']
values = [['grocery'],['orange','apple','kiwi'],['collard', 'spinach']]

my_dict = dict(zip(types, values))

>>> print my_dict
{'type': ['grocery'], 'fruits': ['orange','apple','kiwi'], 'greens': ['collard', 'spinach']}
```

That way if you want to add anything, you just have to do:

```
my_dict['type'].append('dairy')
my_dict['fruits'].append('banana')
```

And if you want to make a new type just use a new name and python will automatically create a new key-value pair as follows:

```
my_dict['meats'] = ['beef', 'chicken', 'fish']
>>> len(my_dict['meats'])    # number of items in 'meats'
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input

```
$ cat f
type         grocery 
fruits       orange
fruits       apple
fruits       kiwi
greens       collard
greens       spinach
```

Awk code :

```
  awk 'NR==1{
              print
              next
            }
            {
              A[$1]=A[$1]?A[$1]","$2:$2
            }
         END{
              for(i in A)
              print i,A[i]
            }' f
```

Resulting

```
type         grocery
greens collard,spinach
fruits orange,apple,kiwi
```

**--edit--**

If order is important try this, input same file twice.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{
              A[$1]=A[$1]?A[$1]","$2:$2
              next
            }
   ($1 in A){
              print $1,A[$1];
              delete A[$1]
            }' f f
```

Resulting

```
type grocery
fruits orange,apple,kiwi
greens collard,spinach
```

Comment: +1 but add `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` to fix your output spacing and possible input issues, and parenthesize your ternary expression for portability and tweak it to not have to specify $2 twice and add the desired blank char after each comma: `A[$1]=(A[$1]?A[$1]", ":"")$2`.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk,

```
awk '{ arr[$1] = arr[$1] ? arr[$1] ", " $2 : $2 } \
END { for (var in arr) print var, " ", arr[var] }' file1.tsv
```

Comment: This worked for me - awk 'FNR==NR{
              A[$1]=A[$1]?A[$1]","$2:$2
              next
            }
   ($1 in A){
              print $1,A[$1];
              delete A[$1]
            }' f f

Answer (score 0):

Another Python solution

```
from collections import defaultdict
from csv import DictReader

d = defaultdict(list)
with open('file1.tsv') as f:                                                
    x = DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for l in x:
            d[l['type']].append(l['grocery'])                               

print " ".join(l.iterkeys())
for k in d:
    print k, ",".join(d[k])
```